# How to find average number of days between orders?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset that I want to find the average number of days between a customer's orders. I want to return `customer_id`, `customer_name`, and `average_days_between_orders`. My first attempt at solving this I ranked the dates and partitioned by `customer_id` and figured I could find the difference between all `order_date`s and then find the average for each customer. I started by subtracting the most recent `order_date` from the end-date of the dataset. However, I could not figure out how to automatically find the differences without hard-coding. Maybe a recursive query is needed, but I'm not very familiar with them.

```
With order_dates_ranked as (
Select customer_id, customer_name, order_date, RANK() OVER(partition by customer_id order by order_date DESC) as date_rank
From orders
Group by customer_id, customer_name, order_date
)

Select customer_id, customer_name, DATEDIFF('2018-01-01', order_date) as days_since_last_order
From order_dates_ranked
Where date_rank = 1
```

Before posting here, I saw a similar question that had been asked and tried its solution as seen below.

```
Select customer_id, customer_name, ROUND((MAX(order_date) - MIN(order_date)) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0), 0) as average
From orders
Group by customer_id, customer_name
Order by average DESC
```

However, this does not work. One customer had two orders over 3 years apart, but the result of this query says the average is 2.

So my goal of this is to find the average number of days between orders taking into consideration the end-date of the dataset (2018-01-01) if possible.

I am using MySQL.

Comment: `Average days between orders = (last order data - first order data) / (orders amount - 1)`

Comment: @Akina This is essentially the same answer as I posted as my second query which does not work. I gave an example on why it does not work as well. Unless it is calculating years instead of days?

Comment: Using DATEDIFF instead of just subtracting and eliminating the NULLIF seemed to fix the issue. But this doesn't solve the issue of having the average affected by the end-date of the dataset. Does merely swapping MAX(order_date) with '2018-01-01' solve this?

Comment: I was about to tell you that you need `DATEDIFF` in MySQL. (They give you weird result values when you subtract dates, instead of raising a syntax error, which is what they should do in my opinion.) You should keep `NULLIF` though. Otherwise your query will crash when there is only one order (division by zero).